# Why use JSON format when read mode and write mode are available?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

Why do we use JSON files when we can as easily store and load data with two other functions, namely `read()` and `write()`?

Since I am a beginner in Python I don't know what else JSON can be used for except to store and load data from different files. Is JSON used for something else, too?

Comment: You *can* use read and write on a file in JSON format, so it's not clear to me what your question is.

Comment: JSON means ***Javascript** Object Notation*. It's primary use is for web programming.

Comment: Can't we do the same thing JSON does without using a JSON file? Only using read() and write() in a file that is not a JSON file.

Comment: Can't we do *what* same thing? There are a lot of file formats anyway, each with benefits and drawbacks. Some are good for large files, some not. Some are easier to read by humans, some not. JSON is just a relatively simple way to represent objects. It's not *The* way to do so, which is why there are formats like Avro, Parquet and ORC. It can't be used for images either

Comment: What else are JSON files used for except to `dump()` and `load()` data? Is there something else they are used for?

Comment: JSON is a widely-used format for storing structured data in string form. There are others (XML was widely used before JSON became popular). JSON is convenient, but it's largely a matter of convention and historical accident - and self-fulfilling prophecy (everyone uses it already, so everyone else wants to use it in order to be able to talk to those services that use it). But it's nothing special in itself, it's just textual data which yes, you can read from and write to a file.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers.

Comment: JSON is a notation/format for data. ``read()`` and ``write()`` are functions to lead/store data. They belong to separate categories. You can do JSON without ``read()``/``write()``, and you can do ``read()``/``write()`` without JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON is a format that can represent certain kinds of structured data (namely dicts and lists, in Python terms). If you have a JSON file that looks like

```
[{"first":"John","last":"Smith"},{"first":"Mary","last":"Smith"}]
```

you know it represents a list of dictionaries, with each dictionary having `first` and `last` key, and the appropriate value.

You could also write this information in many other ways. For example, this format is called YAML:

```
- first: John
  last: Smith
- first: Mary
  last: Smith
```

Or you could represent it in XML like this:

```
<persons>
  <person>
    <first>John</first>
    <last>Smith</last>
  </person>
  <person>
    <first>Mary</first>
    <last>Smith</last>
  </person>
</persons>
```

This format is called CSV:

```
first,last
John,Smith
Mary,Smith
```

Here's one used by PHP:

```
a:2:{i:0;O:8:"stdClass":2:{s:5:"first";s:4:"John";s:4:"last";s:5:"Smith";}i:1;O:8:"stdClass":2:{s:5:"first";s:4:"Mary";s:4:"last";s:5:"Smith";}}
```

You could also homebrew your own format:

```
John (first) Smith (last); Mary (first) Smith (last)
```

Or you could write it like this, in what we programmers call "English":

```
There's two people, you see, one's John Smith.
The other's his wife Mary who took his last name.
```

but good luck on making sense out of that data programmatically later.

It is clear what all but the last have in common: they all encode the same information in a structurally predictable way, so that it can later be read unambiguously into the same structure. All of them but the homebrew and PHP are also more-or-less standardised, so that you don't have to write your own program on how to encode and decode the structure, since there will be libraries which (to a large degree) agree with each other on how the format looks like.

You can certainly use nothing but `write()` and `read()` in order to save and load information; but that's like killing a sheep, tanning hide, cutting leather, sewing it together every time you need shoes - they'll cost more, be uglier and less comfortable than factory-made ones.

Answer (score 0):

Few points about JSON mentioned below,

- Saving a file with extensions like '.txt', '.rtf' etc., we will save
  a file as '.json'. So, that json file should be in a particular
  format that is supported by it.
- It is lightweight and easy to access the object in it.
- For a web application it will act as mediator between front end and back end to process the data quickly.
- REST API provides a response in JSON format

And there are lot more..
Thanks